# Python dynamic equalisation between multiple variables

Tags: python, dynamic

I am a newbie at Python and I have some problems to solve. There's a little piece of my code that I have to rewrite to work dynamically.

```
for j in range(14):
    if nm_0[j] == nm_1[j] == nm_2[j]:
        print(j)
```

Let's suppose that there are 16 pieces of nm_n's (so `nm_0, nm_1, nm_2, nm_3 ... nm_15`) and I have to check the equalisation beetween every nm_n's. How can I write this inside that if function without making a long `nm_0[j] == nm_1[j] == nm_2[j] == nm_3[j] ... == nm_15[j]`?

Comment: `if len(set(nm_0[j], nm_1[j]...nm_15[j])) == 1` or better yet `if len(set(nm[:16][j])) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store them all in a list, so you can use them, no matter how much there is

```
mm0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mm1 = [1, 3, 4, 4]
mm2 = [1, 3, 3, 4]
values = [mm0, mm1, mm2]
for i in range(len(values[0])):
    if len(set(mm[i] for mm in values)) == 1:
        print(i)

# prints 0 and 3
```

Or with `zip`

```
# for i, mm in enumerate(zip(mm0, mm1, mm2)):
for i, mm in enumerate(zip(*values)):
    if len(set(mm)) == 1:
        print(i)
```